# How to copy a Vuex store and import it into a new store

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

I am trying to write a way for in Electron to duplicate Vuex commits from one Window to another with IPC.  This way devs can use the Vuex store between browser windows seamlessly without manually using IPC calls to send everything, causing lots of duplicate code.

So far, I have written a basic Vue plugin to handle pushing commits around

With only some base code using store.subscribe, I IPC send all commits to main, which then forwards the commits to all renderer windows, applying the commits to their respective stores.  Each new browser Windows is able to forward the data to all others.  To prevent endless loops, I check the event and payload and verify it's different than the current value before applying it.

This all works.  It's not even that slow amazingly.  But there is a problem,  When the window is opened, the store is fresh.  I need a way to export the entire store, IPC it to the new window, and import the store.

Is there any way in Vuex to generically export the entire state, then import it again?

Comment: AFAIK the state is just stored inside an object, this.$store.state

Comment: @LielFridman Right but if I set it manually, Vuex should yell at me for changing state outside a mutation.  It also won't be reactive so getters won't be notified of what changed.

Comment: @Trevor not if you set whole state object during store creation...

Comment: Have you tried using [replaceState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#replacestate)

Comment: @dsfx3d I have not, I will try, thanks

Comment: @dsfx3d I think it did work.  No complaints from Vuex, and it correctly updates all the getters when the values appear.  I was able to make a vue plugin to know when the store is loaded, send an ipc request to the main window to get the entire vuex state, copy it over and apply it.  If you post as an answer how to get the state, and how to replaceState, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time, I found a way to sync vuex store between main window and another IPCRenderer Window. I would not explain how to subscribe to mutation using plugins since the question is about replacing the state. Here are the logic steps to replace the state in newWindow:

1. When opening a new window from main window, we can call IPCRenderer
   and send our entire state (**this.$store.state**)

> For example:

```js
this.ipcRenderer.send("open-new-window",cloneObject(this.$store.state));
```

> What we should note here, we could not send a complex object like DOM Object  to our new window because you will get circular JSON error, so here I use script (**UTIL.cloneObject(this.$store.state)**) for convert complex object to avoid circular JSON Error. You can see the code [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#rhc70iqqy6t22yuvhp1hru) or you can find in another place since this question is not about converting to circular json

2. In ipcMain you can store this state in the global variable, for example:

```js
let temporaryState
ipcMain.on('open-new-window', async(event, data) => {
  //Another code...
  newWindow = new BrowserWindow(options);
  temporaryState = data 
   //this is data is your temporary state from mainWindow
  //Another code for open new window
})
```

3. Request to rehydrate state in new window if new window already in "mounted stage", for example:

```js
mounted() {
  this.ipcRenderer.send("ask-rehydrate");
}
```

4. Back to ipcMain, you can listen to rehydrate request from newWindow and send the state that you already store in global variable, for example:

```js
ipcMain.on('ask-rehydrate', (event) => {
  newWindow.webContents.send("currentState", temporaryState);
}
```

5. Listen again in mounted stage to replace the current stage in "newWindow":

```js
mounted() {
  this.ipcRenderer.send("ask-rehydrate");
  this.ipcRenderer.once("currentState", (event, state) => {
       new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       logger.debug("Current state will be replaced with %o", state);
       this.$store.replaceState(state);
       resolve();
   }).then(() => {
       //Do something});
   });
}
```

Congratulation now your state in newWindow will replaced with the current state in main window, here the mutation also sync if you subscribe the mutation using plugin. We should do this in mounted stage of vue since we need to wait until the store already initiated.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I did.  But with the ability to also send all mutations of IPC to keep them in sync, and across all open windows.  I then standardized Vuex to be a global store of data across all Windows.  It's in a few large production apps now and working smoothly.

Comment: Yes, I add this one too, but I wonder how you prevent the infinity loop because I think I did this inefficiently. I create two same mutations with different names and in my plugin only subscribe to one mutation name, then if I want to prevent an infinity loop, I used the second mutation name.

Comment: I am having a funny issue where replaceState doesn't actually trigger getters or anything.  So stuff stays stuck